# ArcPy script not finding empty values in Text fields?

Tags: arcpy, personal-geodatabase

I have written a script that checks populated (or empty) values off of coded value and range domains. It works well with the range domains. It finds empty fields as well as values that are out of range for that field. It also works well when there are values in TEXT fields that don't conform to the accepted domain codes. However, it does not find NULL (None or "") values in TEXT fields.

Here's the code.

```
if ftype in txtList:  ##Start coded value domain checks
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(tbl,['UID',fname,'QAQC_FLAG']) as cur:
    listValues = []  
    for row in cur:
        uid = row[0]
        fieldValue = row[1]
        if fieldValue == None or fieldValue == "":
            insRow = ["VNULL",fname,"","Value not populated with incoming data",uid]
            insCur.insertRow(insRow)
            msg = "Added row {0} to {1}.".format(insRow,qaTbl)
            arcpy.AddMessage(msg)
```

I can't figure out why it won't identify empty fields in the table. Some of these fields have ALL empty values and the script isn't identifying them.

Comment: How do you know it's not identifying the empty field?  You're not telling it to do anything

Comment: It could be whitespace in the field, try fieldValue.replace(' ','').replace('\t','') == "" to remove spaces and tabs in the condition.

Comment: It should insert insRow into another database table with the values in the row. It should also return a message.

Comment: @KenGaines there's nothing in your code snippet that does either of those.  Can you [edit] to include that, as well as whatever messages you receive

Comment: Code edited. I think I may have figured it out. The incoming data came in from an Excel sheet (imported into the pGDB manually). The data originators generate the sheet with some kind of R scripts. Guess what the R script does. It places a <space> character in the fields. This oughta be a lot of fun to figure out.

Comment: Shouldn't your insCur.insertRow be indented one more? Otherwise you're inserting an unmodified row for each feature such that after the first fail all rows will report a false fail.

Comment: That's just me messing up the formatting in here.

Comment: Did somebody say pGDB?!  Jack Dangermond would be turning in his grave if he were dead!

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it could be possible that instead of an empty string `""`, you may have whitespace (one or more spaces `" "` etc).  Maybe test a little more implicitly for "empty" values:

`isEmpty = lambda x: x is not None and str(x).strip() != ""`

Then try that in your if statement:

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(tbl,['UID',fname,'QAQC_FLAG']) as cur:
    listValues = []  
    for row in cur:
        uid = row[0]
        fieldValue = row[1]
        if isEmpty(fieldValue):
            insRow = ["VNULL",fname,"","Value not populated with incoming data",uid]
            # do stuff here
```

And as others have mentioned, the snippet is not actually doing anything after the if statement.

Comment: Do you have any documentation for isEmpty? it's not a function that I know and google can't find it - or rather finds too much 'other' stuff.

Comment: Yup! This is the problem. I will incorporate this piece into the code and test. Many thanks!

Comment: you should be able to use  `if not fieldValue:` to check if the field is empty, otherwise it will contain some white space or whatever else

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson `isEmpty()` is the [lambda function](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/lambda_functions.hawk) I created above the block of code, which I should have clarified that it needs to be in the same code before the cursor.  @Adam  Not necessarily, doing the implicit falsy test by simply using `if not fieldValue:` will also test false if the value is 0 if the field is numeric.  This may not be the case here, but to quote the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) `explicit is better than implicit`